# Why are the GEF children not drawn when removing absolute size of container?

Tags: java, eclipse-gef

I try to get a simple working GEF editor. I have a `GraphicalEditorWithPalette` that creates my example model. I have a `RootEditPart` that overrides `createFigure` and  `getModelChildren` like this:

```
public class RootEditPart extends AbstractGraphicalEditPart {
    @Override
    protected IFigure createFigure() {
        Figure figure = new Figure();
        figure.setOpaque(true);
        figure.setLayoutManager(new XYLayout());
        figure.setSize(1000, 1000);
        return figure;
    }
    @Override
    protected List<Positionable> getModelChildren() {
        return getModel().getChildren();
    }
    // More methods ...
}
```

I have a ChildEditPart that creates a label and override `refreshVisuals` like this:

```
public class ChildEditPart extends AbstractGraphicalEditPart {
    @Override
    protected void refreshVisuals() {
        RDC rdc = getModel();
        Label nameLabel = (Label) getFigure();
        nameLabel.setText(rdc.getName());
        Point position = rdc.getPosition();

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, -1,-1);
        ((GraphicalEditPart) getParent()).setLayoutConstraint(this, nameLabel, r);
    }
    // More methods ...
}
```

This works as expected. But I don't want to have a fixed size for the container. Instead I try to achieve that the containers size adapts to the children. If I remove the `figure.setSize(1000, 1000);` the children are not drawn any more. What is my mistake?

**Edit:**
Maybe it is important to know that my editor configures the root edit part like this: `viewer.setRootEditPart(new ScalableFreeformRootEditPart());`

**Edit2:**
Seems like in fact the call `viewer.setRootEditPart(new ScalableFreeformRootEditPart());` is the problem. If I remove this it works as expected. Currently I don't fully understand why ... would be great if someone could explain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set size of parent's figure manually when it needed.

```
figure.setSize(figure.getPreferredSize());
```

figure delegates computing it's prefer size to it's layout(if exist).
XYLayout will compute minimal size to represent contents.

I think best place to insert this code is setLayoutConstraint of parent EditPart.